# Why my connection is being refused to amazon s3 server?

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, networking

I am a newbie trying to learn how to connect to Amazon S3 in python. I am learning about networking from the book Learn Python Network Programming by M.O. Sarker. I copy-pasted the example and created my amazon access id and key. However, I am getting the error.

The command I ran:
py s3_client.py create_bucket mybuceqeqwqxket.example.com

Here is my code:

```
import sys
import requests
import requests_aws4auth as aws4auth
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import xml.dom.minidom as minidom

access_id = 'REDACTED'
access_key = 'REDACTED'

region = 'ap-south-1'

endpoint = 's3-{}-amazonaws.com'.format(region)
auth = aws4auth.AWS4Auth(access_id, access_key, region, 's3')
ns = 'http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/'

def xml_pprint(xml_string):
    print(minidom.parseString(xml_string).toprettyxml())

def create_bucket(bucket):
    XML = ET.Element('CreateBucketConfiguration')
    XML.attrib['xmlns'] = ns
    location = ET.SubElement(XML, 'LocationConstraint')
    location.text = auth.region
    data = ET.tostring(XML, encoding='utf-8')

    url = 'http://{}.{}'.format(bucket, endpoint)
    r = requests.put(url, data=data, auth=auth)

    if r.ok:
        print('Created bucket {} OK'.format(bucket))
    else:
        xml_pprint(r.text)

if __name__== '__main__':
    cmd, *args = sys.argv[1:]
    globals()[cmd](*args)
```

Here is my error: -

```
s\adapters.py", line 516, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='mybuceqeqwqxket.example.com.s3-ap-south-1-amazonaws.com', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connect
ion.HTTPConnection object at 0x000001BAC8B4B7C0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed'))
```

Comment: Any particular reason why you can't use [boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/index.html) to interact with AWS?

Comment: That hasn't been covered in the book. I am not familiar with the boto. I am just following examples.

Comment: AWS developed a [number of SDKs](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/tools-sdks/) for its services. boto3 is SDK for python and this is what ppl usually use to interact with AWS in their python programs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `endpoint` is incorrect. It should be (check [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_CreateBucket.html#API_CreateBucket_Examples)):

```
endpoint = 's3.{}.amazonaws.com'.format(region)
```

But as I indicated in the comments, its better to use [boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/index.html) to interact with AWS services, rather then handling construction of valid API requests yourself.

Comment: Thanks that helped me. It's not teaching amazing aws but some concepts relating to networking.